# How to Set fonts of OutletCollection of Label?

Tags: ios, swift

I have taken outlet collection of labels and these labels will have same fonts and I want to set the font for all labels in one line.

Answer (score 1):

It will go like this:

```
labels.forEach { $0.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 43) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var labels: [UILabel]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        labels.forEach { (label) in
            label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .semibold)
            //give the font as per your requirement...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get all the labels you want inside an array of Labels

```
let myLabels: [UILabel] = [label1,label2,label3]
```

then make a Loop to set the font of each one of the labels..

```
for text in myLabels {
        text.font = UIFont(name: "Kefa-Regular", size: 10)
         //The 'name' is the name of the font you want, it's also could be a custom one.
    }
```

if it's an `Outlet Collection` you can skip the `Array` part of the code.

Comment: Since it is already an `Outlet Collection`, I don't think there is any need of separate `array`.